# How can I create a custom TextCell and TextRow that has a subclass of UITextField in it?

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I am using [Eureka Forms](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka) and [SearchTextField](https://github.com/apasccon/SearchTextField).

In my form, I want to have something very similar as the (Eureka) built-in `TextRow`. The difference is that this custom `TextRow` will use a `SearchTextField` instead of the regular `UITextField`.

I first thought that I could copy all the code related to `TextRow` and `TextCell` and rename the classes a bit. However, I find the code in `_FieldRow` quite hard to understand and I don't know exactly what code I should copy.

Then I saw that I could set the `cellProvider` property to provide a custom cell:

```
<<< TextRow() {
    $0.cellProvider = CellProvider<TextCell>(nibName: "NewCustomCell", bundle: .main)
    $0.title = "TextRow"
}
```

So I thought I just need an xib file. I tried to find the xib file that Eureka uses for its `TextCell` so that I can copy it and edit it slightly but I couldn't find a single xib file under the `Pods/Eureka` directory. Then I tried to make my own xib file.

After adding a table view cell, I set its class to `TextCell` because I need a `CellProvider<TextCell>`. Then I tried to connect the text fields and labels to the `IBOutlet`s in `_FieldCell` (this is what I'm supposed to do, right?) but the outlets just don't show up. I changed the class to `_FieldCell` and they showed up properly, but I can't pass a nib with a `_FieldCell` into a `CellProvider<TextCell>`, can I?

To reiterate my goal: create a form cell that has a `SearchTextField` as the text field and behaves the same as `TextCell` for everything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use custom rows and cells.. something like this

```
class _SearchTextFieldCell<T>: _FieldCell<T> where T: Equatable, T: InputTypeInitiable {

    required init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {

        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        self.textField.removeFromSuperview()

        let searchTextField = SearchTextField()
        searchTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(searchTextField)
        self.textField = searchTextField
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

class SearchTextCell: _SearchTextFieldCell<String>, CellType {

    required public init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    open override func setup() {
        super.setup()
    }
}

class _SearchTextRow: FieldRow<SearchTextCell> {

    public required init(tag: String?) {
        super.init(tag: tag)
    }
}

final class SearchTextRow: _SearchTextRow, RowType {

    required public init(tag: String?) {
        super.init(tag: tag)
    }
}
```

then you can use the custom row with

```
<<< SearchTextRow() {

    $0.title = "Search"

    guard let tf = $0.cell.textField as? SearchTextField else {
        return
    }

    tf.filterStrings(["lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet"])
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked! Can you explain how the text field is positioned so nicely when you have set no constraints or frame or anything?

Comment: you're welcome :) for the constraints, i've set self.textField = searchTextField. in  the  _FieldCell<T> class, there is a function  customConstraints() , which sets the constraints of self.textField. As _SearchTextFieldCell is a subclass of _FieldCell<T>, the function called will still belong to the superclass, as the subclass did not override the customConstraints() function. in the customConstraints() function, the constraints are being set on self.textField, which in this case is equals to the SearchTextField which was assigned to self.textField.